# How i share information of multiple shared buffers between to seperate processes?

Tags: linux, memory-management, process, ipc, shared-memory

I have two separate linux processes, Process A creates 'N' number of shared buffers. Now i have a Process B that wants to use this buffers created by process A. How can i share information about the shared buffers with Process B?

Comment: Wow, maybe I'm just missing what you are asking. What do you mean when you say "*Process A creates 'N' number of shared buffers.*"? Moreover, what is "*Process A*"? A C-program? A daemon? How and where are the buffers created? `shm_open`?

Comment: You can say Process-A implements a factory method and creates shared buffers (all of same size) on request as and when process B wants it.   Yes, both programs are C-programs, But i am not sure whether i should be using shm_open() or shm_get().

Comment: `shm_open` will do what you want (I don't find a `shm_get`). `shm_open` will create and open a new shared memory object, or it will open an existing memory object. I think you are safe there. [**shm_open(3) - Linux man page**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open)

Comment: yes shm_open() takes a (const char *name) as first argument, my problem is how this name is going to be communicated to the Process-B by process-A. Process-A generates a random string on-the-fly and create a buffer out of it.

Comment: Are the processes `fork`ed from the same initial process? A-could generate, then fork B that would inherit all the current environment from A?

Comment: No they are separate binaries and not forked processes.

Comment: Here is a good walkthrough [**IPC:Shared Memory**](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node27.html)